# Is it Possible to revert back Hadoop data from druid?

Tags: hadoop, hive, druid

I have Mistakenly deleted data from Hadoop. These data i have in Druid ,now i want to restore these data from Druid to Hadoop to avoid further data recovery problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you might be having similar metastore, try creating ctas in hive pulling data from druid and store it in Hadoop location.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Hive**

Create an external hive table backed by existing data source, this will give you all the data in hive on an HDFS location.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE druid_table_1
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.druid.DruidStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES ("druid.datasource" = "<datasource_name>");
```

You can also specify STORED AS property to this DDL, if you want to store it any particular format.

You can find more details about Druid-Hive intergeation here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Druid+Integration

**Using dump segment**

If you want to dump metadata/data of segment then dump segment utility can be useful here.

```
java org.apache.druid.cli.Main tools dump-segment \
--directory /home/druid/path/to/segment/ \
--out /home/druid/output.txt
```

More details can be found here: 
http://druid.io/docs/latest/operations/dump-segment.html

This second approach works for a single segment so in the case where you want to dump entire table or multiple segments then you need to write a small script to run this command recursively on that directory.

Comment: Is it possible without Hive,I hv 1TB data , Which may cause problem in Hive ?                  I want any plugin that should simply store data from  Druid to Hadoop . Because Druid store these data read only format  from Hadoop.So is  their way where  we can store directly back to hadoop.

Comment: @SudhanshuLenka Hive table should be fine with 1TB of data, if you partition and/or bucketed them properly then you can even use it for query and it will return results in reasonable response time. Loading data from druid to hive using Insert select / CTAS might be slow but you can insert these data in intervals.